How to Find the Maximum Possible Value of the 90th Percentile Given a Fixed Mean?
Problem:
If we have a list where the minimum element is -10 and the mean of the list is 55.2, what is the maximum possible value the 90th percentile could be?
My Approach So Far:
I understand that the 90th percentile is the value below which 90% of the data falls, so in a list of 20 elements, the 19th element would be the 90th percentile.
To maximize the 90th percentile, then I would want to keep the first 18 elements as low as possible (-10), and adjust the last two elements accordingly.
The issue is since I don't know the size of the list, I'm having trouble tackling this problem.

You're on the right track--you just need to keep reasoning.
The quantiles of a dataset are not universally defined, so we will adopt the following convention:  the $90^{\rm th}$ percentile of an ordered list of $n$ observations corresponds to the $\lceil (0.9)n \rceil^{\rm th}$ observation.  So for instance, if $n = 10$, the $90^{\rm th}$ percentile is the $9^{\rm th}$ observation when ranked in ascending order, and if $n = 11$, the $90^{\rm th}$ percentile is the $\lceil 9.9 \rceil = 10^{\rm th}$ such observation.  (This convention corresponds to the first entry in the table in the Wikipedia article--i.e., it is the inverse of the empirical cumulative distribution function.)
As you correctly observed, the $90^{\rm th}$ percentile, which we will call $q$, is largest when every observation below it is as small as possible, thus equal to $-10$.  But for the same reason, this also must apply to any observations ordered after $q$.
To see why, suppose there is an ordered dataset $$S = (x_{(1)}, \ldots, x_{(k)}, q, x_{(k+2)}, \ldots, x_{(n)})$$ where $q$ is the $90^{\rm th}$ percentile, satisfying $\bar x = 55.2$.  That is to say, the sample total $\Sigma S = (55.2)n$.  Now if we compare this to another dataset,
$$S' = (x_{(1)}, \ldots, x_{(k)} + \delta_1, q', x_{(k+2)}, \ldots, x_{(n)}),$$ where $0 < \delta_1 < q - x_{(k)}$, we can see that the $90^{\rm th}$ percentile has not changed position; but in order for the sample mean to remain constant, $\delta_1 + q' - q = 0$.  Consequently, we must have $q' = q - \delta_1 < q$.  Similarly, in the dataset
$$S'' = (x_{(1)}, \ldots, x_{(k)}, q'', x_{(k+2)}, \ldots, x_{(n)} + \delta_2)$$
where $0 < \delta_2$, again the $90^{\rm th}$ percentile has not changed position, but we would need $\delta_2 + q'' - q = 0$, or $q'' < q$.  It follows that in order to maximize $q$, we must minimize all of the other elements in the dataset under the constraint that $q$ retains the same rank.  So we may assume without loss of generality that the dataset has the structure
$$S = (-10, -10, \ldots, -10, q, q, \ldots, q)$$
where there are strictly fewer than $9$ times as many instances of $-10$ as there are instances of $q$.
So how do we take into account the variable sample size?  This is the part where you got stuck.  Well, suppose we have a sample size $n = 10a + b$ for some positive integer $a$ and some nonnegative integer $b \in \{0, 1, \ldots, 9\}$.  Then the $90^{\rm th}$ percentile is the $$\lceil (0.9)(10a + b) \rceil = \lceil 9a + (0.9)b \rceil = 9a + \lceil (0.9)b \rceil = (9a+b)^{\rm th}$$ observation.  So we have $9a + b - 1$ instances of $-10$, and $a + 1$ instances of $q$.  So the sample total is
$$(55.2)(10a) = (-10)(9a+b-1) + q(a+1),$$
which implies
$$q = 642 - \frac{2(326-5b)}{a+1}.$$  Since $0 \le b \le 9$ and $a \ge 1$, the fractional term is never negative, and tends to $0$ as $a \to \infty$; hence $q$ tends to $642$, so this is the least upper bound.

Let $N$ be the number of observations. This means that the 90th percentile is the element with index $K = \lceil 0.9*N \rceil$. So, we have $K-1$ entries at -10 and $N-K+1$ entries at some unknown value $X$.
Since the mean is 55.2,
$-10(K-1) + X(N-K+1) = 55.2N$
$X = \frac{55.2N + 10(K-1)}{N-K+1}$
If $N=10$, you get $K=9$, thus $X=316$
If $N=1000$, you get $K=900$, thus $X=635.5$
If $N=1000000$, you get $K=900000$, thus $X = 641.99$, etc.
In general, if you consider the limit $N >> 1$, i.e. $K \approx 0.9N$, you get $X \approx (55.2N + 9N)/0.1N = 642$, as shows by @heropup above
